How to get copyright status of a video that I am uploading via YouTube Data API?
Is there a way to get the copyright check status of a video via the YouTube APIs? Similar to the one found when a video is uploaded via the web UI under the checks section. When I try uploading a video via the API, it does not return any information related to copyright.

Check the documentation:



Properties





status.rejectionReason
string



This value explains why YouTube  rejected an uploaded video. This property is only present if the uploadStatus property indicates that the upload was rejected. Valid values for this property are:- claim- copyright- duplicate- inappropriate- legal- length- termsOfUse- trademark- uploaderAccountClosed- uploaderAccountSuspended




This only tells you if the video has been taken down because of a copyright issue, not if you are unable to monetize it because of copyright claims.
